# Python Pass List into Form and Retrieve as List

Tags: python, cgi

What is the best way to pass List via form in python (cgi).

```
ListStr = ['State1', 'State2', 'State3']
TrVListStr = '##'.join(ListStr)


print """
   <form method="post">
   <input type=hidden name="state_carry" value="""+TrVListStr+"""><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form> 
"""
```

After submission I should have list as it was before submission.

I can do split (based on ## rule) form['state_carry].value again to fetch that. but I think it is not good way.

Is there any way to pass Python List via form and retrieve them later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the python [cgi module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html). The documentation [specifically covers](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module) the case where you have multiple values for a certain field name.

The basic idea is that you can have multiple fields in your html form with the same name, and the value for each field is one of the values from the list. You can then use the [`getlist()`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.FieldStorage.getlist) method to retrieve all the values as a list. For example:

```
print "<form method=\"post\">"

for s in ListStr:
    print "<input type=hidden name=\"state_carry\" value=\"" + s + "\"><br />"

print "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />"
print "</form>"
```

Then in your CGI script you'll have something like:

```
MyList = form.getlist("state_carry")
```

Comment: I found it is tedious to pass list specially when
1. List is Big
2. Multiple continuous pass.

So I found it is better to store in a file locally.

Answer (score 1):

In python I would do.

```
###In the form page.
import cgi

#Convert list of values to string before passing them to action page.
ListStr=','.join(['State1', 'State2', 'State3'])

print "<input type=hidden name=\"state_carry\" value=\""+ListStr+"\"><br />"

###In the action page
import cgi

#Return the string passed in the user interaction page and transform it back to a list.
ListStr=cgi.FieldStorage().getvalue('state_carry').split(',')
```